# Ajax posting data into a excel sheet

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, excel

So I try to put data into a Excel sheet, I do it this way,

first is send the data via a ajax post:

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#form").on('submit', function() {
    $(function() {
        var hello = "hello world";
        $.ajax ({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'example.php',
            data: {hello: hello},
            success: function(result) {
                console.log('success');
            }
        });
    });
   });
    });
    </script>
   <body>
   <form id="form" action="example.php" method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Then I put it into a excel sheet:

```
   <?php 
   include "../includes/PHPExcel.php";

   $title = "Verrijking ";

   $hello = $_POST['hello'];

   $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
   $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("RM Netherlands B.V.")
        ->setLastModifiedBy("RM Netherlands B.V.")
        ->setTitle($title)
        ->setSubject($title)
        ->setDescription($title)
        ->setKeywords($title)
        ->setCategory($title);

   $pcbestand = date('Ymdhis') . ".xlsx";

   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->setCellValue("A"."1", $hello);
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension("A")->setAutoSize(true);


   $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
   $objWriter->save($pcbestand);

   $file = $pcbestand;
   header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);
   header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
   header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
   header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
   header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
   header('Pragma: public');
   ob_clean();
   flush();
   readfile($file);

  $DelFilePath = $setup['/var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/nordin/'.$pcbestand.''] . $pcbestand;

  if (file_exists($DelFilePath)) { unlink ($DelFilePath); }
  ?>
```

the last part create's a save as file dialog and make's sure it isn't uploaded to the server.

But this is the problem I don't get the ajax post ($_POST['hello']) into my excel sheet even tho the ajax post is successful. What am I doing wrong? please help.

Comment: There's two issues here. The first is that you don't have any `e.preventDefault()` in your `on('submit')` callback, which will make your form to be submitted "normally" and not with Ajax and your JS (which is why you get the download prompt). The second issue is that you can't use Ajax if you want to download the response. Put your `hello` in a hidden input `<input type="hidden" name="hello" value="Hello World" />` in your form, remove your JS and it will work.

Comment: yes thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two issues here. The first is that you don't have any e.preventDefault() in your click() callback, which will make your form to be submitted "normally" without your JS (which is why you get the download prompt). The second issue is that you can't use Ajax if you want to download the response. Put your hello in a hidden input in your form and remove your JS and it will work. – Magnus Eriksson

This worked all credit to Magnus Eriksson.